# How to get target directory of other project under same solution fo post build action of project (VS C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build-event

I have solution which has 2 projects
Project1.csproj, Project2.csproj.
I have a need to get output directory of Project2 in post build actions of Project1.
I can get target directory (TargetDir) for Project1.
How can I get output directory of Project2 for post build actions of Project1 ?

Comment: Please refer to [How to: Specify build events (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022#macros). Commonly used "macros" (actually MSBuild properties) are listed in MSBuild Common Properties. For .NET SDK projects (.NET Core or .NET 5 and above)